# How do implement panel feature in Xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, navigation, xamarin.forms

Like in Windows Forms we can add multiple panels in the same Form and based on some condition show and hide particular panel. Is there any control in `Xamarin.Forms` which can be used like this?

The main reason behind this is, I have 3 tabs on a page. I am using buttons for tabs and not tabbed pages as design of tabbed bar is not what my client wants. So I have 3 pages say `Page A`, `Page B`, `Page C` and each of the page has 3 tabs to go to respective page. If user is on `Page A` and fills some sort of data(which is not yet saved) and wants to go to `Page B` and then on `Page B` he fills in some more details and then without saving data on `Page B` when he comes back to `Page A` all the details filled by user on `Page A` and `Page B` has to be available.

Hence If I use multiple pages for this then the data will be lost when I redirect to new page. So Is there any way by which I have multiple panels and hide 1st panel when 2nd panel is visible which will not clear any data and hence I can achieve what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just hide the panels that aren't being used (using the `IsVisible` property) - this pulls them out of the visual tree but does not release them from memory.

If you create a Content View for each page, then you can easily use them in your main UI such as in this example. Even though we are hiding the individual panels they will still remain in memory while hidden:

MyView.cs (this could be anything you want in your panels):

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace FormsSandbox
{
    public class MyView : ContentView
    {
        public static BindableProperty TextProperty = BindableProperty.Create("Text", typeof(string), typeof(MyView), 
            String.Empty, BindingMode.Default, null, TextChanged);

        public string Text {
            get {
                return (string)GetValue (TextProperty);
            }
            set {
                SetValue (TextProperty, value);
            }
        }

        private Label _contentLabel;

        public MyView ()
        {
            _contentLabel = new Label {
                FontSize = 56,
                FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold,
                HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
                VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center
            };
            Content = _contentLabel;
        }

        static void TextChanged (BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            var view = (MyView)bindable;
            view._contentLabel.Text = (newValue ?? "").ToString ();
        }
    }
}
```

XamlPage.xaml (main UI page):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:sandbox="clr-namespace:FormsSandbox"
    x:Class="FormsSandbox.XamlPage">
    <ContentPage.Padding>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness" iOS="0,20,0,0" Android="0" WinPhone="0"/>
    </ContentPage.Padding>

    <Grid RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Button Text="1" Clicked="ButtonClicked" x:Name="Button1" Grid.Column="0" />
        <Button Text="2" Clicked="ButtonClicked" x:Name="Button2" Grid.Column="1" />
        <Button Text="3" Clicked="ButtonClicked" x:Name="Button3" Grid.Column="2" />

        <sandbox:MyView Text="1" x:Name="View1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
        <sandbox:MyView Text="2" x:Name="View2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
        <sandbox:MyView Text="3" x:Name="View3" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
    </Grid>

</ContentPage>
```

XamlPage.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace FormsSandbox
{
    public partial class XamlPage : ContentPage
    {
        public XamlPage ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
            SelectButton (Button1);
        }

        void SelectButton(Button button)
        {
            View view = null;
            if (button == Button1)
                view = View1;
            if (button == Button2)
                view = View2;
            if (button == Button3)
                view = View3;
            View1.IsVisible = View1 == view;
            View2.IsVisible = View2 == view;
            View3.IsVisible = View3 == view;
            Button1.TextColor = (Button1 == button) ? Color.Accent.AddLuminosity(0.18) : (Color)Button.TextColorProperty.DefaultValue;
            Button2.TextColor = (Button2 == button) ? Color.Accent.AddLuminosity(0.18) : (Color)Button.TextColorProperty.DefaultValue;
            Button3.TextColor = (Button3 == button) ? Color.Accent.AddLuminosity(0.18) : (Color)Button.TextColorProperty.DefaultValue;
            Button1.BackgroundColor = (Button1 == button) ? Color.Silver.AddLuminosity(0.18) : Color.Silver.AddLuminosity(0.1);
            Button2.BackgroundColor = (Button2 == button) ? Color.Silver.AddLuminosity(0.18) : Color.Silver.AddLuminosity(0.1);
            Button3.BackgroundColor = (Button3 == button) ? Color.Silver.AddLuminosity(0.18) : Color.Silver.AddLuminosity(0.1);
        }

        void ButtonClicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SelectButton ((Button)sender);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Running example]

Comment: Could you please take a look at [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36641270/access-controls-from-view-in-content-page). I am unable to access contentview entry field in my contentPage

Comment: I took a look at that question as well and added an answer that should help. Please mark as answer if it works for you so others don't spend time trying to fix a problem that you're no longer stuck on :).

Answer (score 1):

You can save this data to a cache and load it from there.

```
public static class MyDataCache 
{
    public static MyData MyData { get; } = new MyData();
}

// in your pages
protected override void OnAppearing()
{            
    base.OnAppearing();
    // set data from MyDataCache.MyData
    MyProperty = MyDataCache.MyData.MyProperty;
}

protected override void OnDisappearing()
{            
    base.OnDisappearing();
    // set data to MyDataCache.MyData
    MyDataCache.MyData.MyProperty = MyProperty;
}
```

But be aware: It's just a memory cache. If the App gets tombstoned, the data will be lost. You can try this approach first and see if its fits your need. After that, you should store the data in a temporary storage (e.g. with [Akavache](https://github.com/akavache/Akavache)). You should not rebuild this page navigation behavior with something custom.

Comment: By saving it to cache, the values will still persist on page change?

Comment: Yes. its a static class. Its in the memory as long as the app is in memory. You just have to fill your properties when the page appears.

Comment: Just to confirm, On load of the page say `Page A` I am reading data from xml file serialize it and displaying it in textboxes and other controls, when user goes to `Page B` it will call onDisappearing and save the data in static variable. Then when I return back from `Page B` to `Page A` I will again have to populate my controls with saved data from static variables?

Comment: I had written my code of reading xml file and populating controls in the constructor of the page, I would have to move to onAppear?

Comment: Yes, I think so :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use a Frame:

```
<StackLayout>
    <Frame x:Name="MyPanelABC">
        <Label Text="My Stuff" />
    </Frame>
</StackLayout>

private void setupPanelABC(bool isVisiblePanelABC){
    MyPanelABC.IsVisible = isVisiblePanelABC;
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) will help people understand the reasons for your code suggestion.